# Rx onErrorReturn is not called when test case run

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, rx-java

I have

```
public Single<APIResponse> getPayment(Identity identity, String id) {
    return client.getPayment(identity, id).onErrorReturn(__ -> getTheSameEntityIfError(id));
}
```

`client` is a web-service client which call external service
In case of any error returned from `client.getPayment`, then it will call `getTheSameEntityIfError(id)`

I am trying to write a test case to cover this method

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AdapterTest {

    @Mock
    PaymentsClient client;

    @InjectMocks
    Adapter adapter;

    Identity identity = testIdentity();
    PaymentEntity payment = testPayment();

    @Test
    public void getPayment() {
        when(client.getPayment(any(), any())).thenThrow(new NotFoundException());
        APIResponse apiResponse = adapter.getPayment(identity, "id").blockingGet();
        assertThat(payment.getId(), equalTo(apiResponse.getId(1)));
    }
}
```

I this case i want to simulate if the external service  `client.getPayment()` returns an error, then call `getTheSameEntityIfError(id)`.
I expect the `onErrorReturn` operation will be called, but it always throw `NotFoundException` and the `onErrorReturn` never called.

Any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: You mock `client.getPayment()` to throw instead of returning something RxJava can work with, thus RxJava doesn't even get involved in this case. Make `client.getPayment` return a `Single.error()`.

Comment: @akarnokd Work like magic. Please add your comment as an answer so i can accept it as the correct one. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mock `client.getPayment()` to throw instead of returning something RxJava can work with, thus RxJava doesn't even get involved in this case. Make `client.getPayment` return a `Single.error()`.